# Finding UMVUE of function of poisson parameter

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

I am to estimate $exp(-\lambda)\lambda^2/2$ from the distribution $Exp(\lambda) \sim \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!}$

I used the Indicator function $I_{X_1=2}(X)$ as an initial unbias estimator. statistic $T=\sum{X_i}$. Using Rao-Blackwell, $\hat{W} = E(W|T) = \frac{t(t-1)(n-1)^{t-2}}{2n^t}$

However, when I check $E(\hat{W}) = \sum_{t=0}^{n}\frac{t(t-1)(n-1)^{t-2}e^{-n\lambda}(n\lambda)^t}{2n^tt!}=\frac{1}{2}\exp(-n\lambda)\lambda^2$.

Where is the n coming from and how do i get rid of it? Where did i made a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but following your procedure (that is correct)

$$W=\mathbb{1}_{\{2\}}(X_1)$$

thus using the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)

$$\mathbb{E}[\hat{W}]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[W|T]]=\mathbb{E}[W]=1\cdot \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^2}{2}+0\cdot\left[1-\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^2}{2}\right]=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^2}{2}$$

---

Direct calculation

$$\mathbb{E}[\hat{W}]=\sum_{t=0}^{n}\frac{t(t-1)(n-1)^{t-2}}{2\cdot n^t}\cdot\frac{e^{-n\lambda}(n\lambda)^t}{t!}=$$

$$=\frac{e^{-n\lambda}\lambda^2}{2}\sum_{t-2=0}^{n}\frac{[(n-1)\lambda]^{t-2}}{(t-2)!}=\frac{e^{-n\lambda}\lambda^2}{2}\cdot e^{(n-1)\lambda}=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^2}{2}$$

Comment: elegant use of tower rule, but why can't I calculate $E(\hat{W})$ directly from what I have? Using tower rule would ensure that $W$ is correct but if i make a mistake (and i tend to a lot) when calculating $E(W|T)$ this checking wouldn't help.

Comment: @smaillis : done!

Answer (score 0):

your initial unbiased estimator looks fine to me...using standard procedure I get exactly the resutl you will expect.

$$\mathbb{E}[W|T]=\mathbb{P}[W=1|T=t]=\frac{\mathbb{P}[X_1=2]\cdot\mathbb{P}[T=t|X_1=2]}{\mathbb{P}[T=t]}=$$

$$=\frac{\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^2}{2!}\cdot\mathbb{P}[\Sigma_{i=2}^n=t-2]}{\frac{e^{-n\lambda}(n\lambda)^t}{t!}}=$$

$$=\frac{\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^2}{2!}\cdot\frac{e^{-(n-1)\lambda}[(n-1)\lambda]^{t-2}}{(t-2)!}}{\frac{e^{-n\lambda}(n\lambda)^t}{t!}}=\frac{t(t-1)(n-1)^{t-2}}{2\cdot n^t}$$

Comment: so I made a mistake when calculating $E(\hat{W}|T)$? how can i get rid of the n in $\exp(-n\lambda)$?

Comment: @smaillis as  you can see in my calculations it simplifies with the numerator. If you want to see all the algebraic calculations why do not you accept this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4054623/finding-the-umvue-of-variance-of-exponential-distribution/4054702#4054702 first? This will encourage me to spend more time in typing all the calculations

Comment: sorry, I forgot about the other question

Comment: @smaillis : I added one more passage...it's a key passage...I think it is enough...is it?

Comment: I got how to calculate $E(W|T)$, but i still don't understand why my $E(\hat{W})$ has an n in it. So now my problem is figuring out where i went wrong in my checking.

Comment: @smaillis: sorry I misunderstood your issue....let me check...be patient, English is not my first language...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120651/discussion-between-smaillis-and-tommik).